# Packaged python .app file crashing, but packaged python .sh file working fine

Tags: python, macos, pyqt4, cx-freeze

I've produced an app using Python 3.4.3, Pyqt4 and some other extras (Poppler being among them) on OS X Yosemite.

I'm using cx_freeze to produce a working .app file and eventually, a working msi file. I've been testing the app works properly after building it using the build command as in "python3 setup.py build". This all works fine, no unexpected crashes.
Moved on to packaging it using "python3 setup.py bdist_dmg". Opened the dmg file/app file, they crash instantly giving this error:

```
Process:               main [1098]
Path:                  /Users/USER/*/FYP-0.1.app/Contents/MacOS/main
Identifier:            main
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           main [1098]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-05-12 02:18:16.867 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D131)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        8A613A61-D35F-9A4C-8E97-57069A95BF20


Time Awake Since Boot: 1300 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
__TEXT                 0000000103135000-0000000103138000 [   12K] r-  x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/*/FYP-0.1.app/Contents/MacOS/main

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   QtGui                           0x000000010ecf126b   QApplication::setActiveWindow(QWidget*) + 315
1   QtGui                           0x000000010ec90b7d  onApplicationWindowChangedActivation(QWidget*, bool) + 100
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8e99045c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8e880634 _CFXNotificationPost + 3140
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff94cd29d1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9048dbd9 -[NSWindow becomeKeyWindow] + 1406
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9048cf3e -[NSWindow _changeKeyAndMainLimitedOK:] + 795
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9048cb36 -[NSWindow _makeKeyRegardlessOfVisibility] + 98
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9048ca9e -[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:] + 27
9   QtGui                           0x00000001045cfea7 QWidgetPrivate::show_sys() + 629
10  QtGui                           0x000000010466c39c QWidgetPrivate::show_helper() + 432
11  QtGui                           0x000000010466ccce QWidget::setVisible(bool) + 800
12  PyQt4.QtGui.so                  0x0000000103f40634 sipQMainWindow::setVisible(bool) + 100
13  PyQt4.QtGui.so                  0x00000001040f7ed9 meth_QWidget_show(_object*, _object*) + 105
14  Python                          0x0000000103315ad5 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22129
15  Python                          0x0000000103318f12 fast_function + 203
16  Python                          0x0000000103315964 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 21760
17  Python                          0x00000001033102ad PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1622
18  Python                          0x000000010329e7ab function_call + 372
19  Python                          0x000000010327e576 PyObject_Call + 103
20  Python                          0x000000010328fca8 method_call +   136
21  Python                          0x000000010327e576 PyObject_Call + 103
22  Python                          0x00000001032c45b2 slot_tp_init + 57
23  Python                          0x00000001032c1b48 type_call + 172
24  Python                          0x000000010327e576 PyObject_Call + 103
25  Python                          0x000000010331582a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 21446
26  Python                          0x00000001033102ad PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1622
27  Python                          0x000000010330fc51 PyEval_EvalCode + 63
28  Python                          0x000000010330d6e3 builtin_exec + 536
29  Python                          0x0000000103315ad5 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22129
30  Python                          0x00000001033102ad PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1622
31  Python                          0x000000010330fc51 PyEval_EvalCode + 63
32  main                            0x0000000103136cc5 main + 1957
33  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff986995c9 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff91651232 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff96fd0a6a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9165094a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff92c4e40d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9165094a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff92c4e40d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9165094a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff92c4e40d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9165094a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff92c4e40d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9165094a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff92c4e40d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fbe8322a670  rcx: 0x00007fbe8326d0a0  rdx: 0x0000000000000002
  rdi: 0x00007fbe8322a670  rsi: 0x0000000000000001  rbp: 0x00007fff5cac8ea0  rsp: 0x00007fff5cac8df0
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x00007fbe830f90a0  r10: 0x0000000000000011  r11: 0x00007fff7bbdc190
  r12: 0x00007fbe8322a670  r13: 0x00000000000f42cd  r14: 0x00007fbe83296370  r15: 0x000000010f578228
  rip: 0x000000010ecf126b  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14
```

There's a load more but I'm not sure how much is relevant. Here is my setup.py file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

zips = ["implementation/primaries/GUI/designer_files",
         "implementation/primaries/GUI/themes",     "implementation/primaries/GUI/images",
     "implementation/primaries/scripts"]
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"],
                 "include_files":zips}


setup(
    name='FYP',
    version='0.1',
    packages=['implementation', 'implementation.primaries',     'implementation.primaries.GUI', 'implementation.primaries.scripts',
              'implementation.primaries.GUI.pyqt_plugins',     'implementation.primaries.Drawing',     'implementation.primaries.Drawing.classes',
          'implementation.primaries.Drawing.classes.tree_cls',     'implementation.primaries.ExtractMetadata',
              'implementation.primaries.ExtractMetadata.classes',     'implementation.primaries.ImportOnlineDBs','implementation.primaries.ImportOnlineDBs.classes'],
    description='MuseLib',
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("implementation/main.py", base=base)]
)
```

Not sure what the problem is, I saw a few other people having similar problems but they seem to be on either older versions of Python or older versions of OS X, and the fixes didn't solve my problem. Any suggestions for how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: The crash appears to be coming from `FYP-0.1.app/Contents/MacOS/main` with the function `setActiveWindow(QWidget*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a better way to debug this: right click on the app file, "view package contents", MacOS > select the executable with the same name as the file given in setup.py (for me this was main). 
Error I then got:
`QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice`

I fixed this by initialising my Application object, then initialising my main window object, then showing the main window, and then calling a load method which set up the window. I was originally doing that part inside the constructor which was for some reason giving problems.
I'm now having issues with opening/closing windows and opening others on close, but that's probably best for another question or session of googling.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be missing QtGui dll files. I haven't used cx_freeze for packaging on OS X, but generally you have to put (QtCore, QtGui) dlls into the working directory. Did you try other examples with QtGui in your setup?

Comment: I'm pretty sure cx_freeze does that itself by doing a scan of the included files, hence they appear inside the folder where the main program gets put when I run build. Checking the other examples now but I can't see what's wrong.